# How to render HTML into video?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, video, mern

With NodeJS, is there a scalable way to:

1. Grab a web page's html
2. Render it into a mp4 video that looks like someone scrolling on it

I thought about using puppeteer with ffmpeg but that sounds resource intensive (please correct me if I'm wrong.)

The aim is to run this on an AWS server when a button is pressed, by multiple users, at the same time, so it'd have to be scalable and optimized.

Thoughts?

**Edit:** Sorry if I wasn't clear, the intention is:

1. *Have the user enter a url, then press a button*
2. Return a video that looks like someone scrolling on it.

It's part of a bigger feature

Comment: Why not show a pre-recorded video to show to users?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, the intention is:

Have the user enter a url, press a button, then return a video that looks like someone scrolling on it.

It's part of a bigger feature

Comment: So might just want to host a video on the internet? [Example](https://tonicsiteshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/DEMO-TONIC-Free-Launch-Graphics.mp4)

Comment: I'm wording it really badly. I mean record a video scrolling on the website they entered the url to. Sounds weird but it's part of a bigger feature.